# Passing a function from Context to a component to update state in context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having issues passing a function from my context that sets the state inside the context to a component.  The function is coming back undefined when I console log it, but everything else in the context shows up when I console log them. It's supposed to update the state of "display" inside my context from the Header component. I've tried finding solutions on stack overflow but nothing has worked so far. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/joeyjr95/max-kaplan-portfolio/tree/master/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: could you please provide a codesandbox for us to debug?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/joeyjr95/max-kaplan-portfolio/tree/master/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: let me check. `setDisplay` is the method you want?

Comment: yeah it's not passing down to the component correctly

Comment: what should be the expected behaviour?

Comment: It should show the menu when you click the button in the top right corner

Comment: Right. Got it. Did you copy paste the code?

Comment: Such a big issue, if you copy pasted, else may be just a typo.

Comment: Just figured it out. Was a syntax error in the index. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

There was a tiny syntax error in the index. This is how the index should look. Take a look at the PortProvider.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <PortProvider>
    <App />
    </PortProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root"),
  console.log(PortProvider)
);
```

the original:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App/App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { PortProvider } from "./Context/Context";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <PortProvider/>
    <App />
    <PortProvider/>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root"),
  console.log(PortProvider)
);
```

Comment: That's what I pointed too. but I think By this. context should be undefined.

Comment: you should still, see the code in my answer. simplified the setDisplay logic into a single statement, value object in render completely not needed as it's a copy of state. Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

A few tiny issues, Typo in `index.js` self-closing `<Provider/>` and Useless default value, as it is replaced by state. Changed the menu `<a>` to `<div>`. Optimized `setDisplay`, also passed it as `toggle` then used where required.

```
<PortContext.Provider value={{ ...this.state, toggle: this.setDisplay }}>
    {this.props.children}
</PortContext.Provider>
```

[Fixed Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-wilbur-duobz)

Comment: When i do that I get this error:
```
Line 161:36:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  159 |     // };
  160 |     return (
> 161 |       <PortContext.Provider value={...this.state}>
      |                                    ^
  162 |         {this.props.children}
  163 |       </PortContext.Provider>
  164 |     );
```

Comment: it is a `systax error message` , be careful for any syntax errors.

Comment: Hi, i just notice your value object has a missing `'` after closed. thus it leads to a syntax error.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/joeyjr95/max-kaplan-portfolio/tree/master/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark